# Saving data for an Android application using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, save

I have completed the layout of my application and now I just need to do the actual programming of it. I have an "In Game Menu" which has a text field at the top. This text field can be edited by an EditText that is located on a different page, known as "Team Details". When the EditText has a string put into it, the string appears in the text field at the top of "In Game Menu". This is exactly what I want to happen. However, when I go to another page and return to "In Game Menu", the string at the top of the page has disappeared. I don't know how to make the string stay at the top of the page permanently and I would love it if someone could help me!

The code on "Team details"

```
package com.footballmanagerlog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class teamDetails extends Activity{

TextView textOut;
EditText getInput;
String TeamName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.teamdetails);

    textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuteamname);
    getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameTeam);

    Button bbuttondone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondone);
    bbuttondone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TeamName = getInput.getText().toString();               
            Intent TeamNameIntent = new Intent("com.footballmanagerlog.GOTOINGAMEMENU");                
            TeamNameIntent.putExtra("TeamName", TeamName);              
            startActivity(TeamNameIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

and the code on "In Game Menu"

```
package com.footballmanagerlog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class inGameMenu extends Activity{

TextView teamname;
String teamnamestring;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ingamemenu);

    TextView teamname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuteamname); 
    Intent teamnameintenttwo = getIntent();
    teamnamestring = teamnameintenttwo.getStringExtra("TeamName");
    teamname.setText(teamnamestring);

    Button bbuttonmatch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonmatch);
    bbuttonmatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.footballmanagerlog.GOTOFORMATION"));

        }
    });

    Button bbuttonsubsidiaries = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsubsidiaries);
    bbuttonsubsidiaries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.footballmanagerlog.GOTOSUBSIDIARIES"));

        }
    }); 

    Button bbuttonstatistics = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstatistics);;
    bbuttonstatistics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.footballmanagerlog.GOTOSTATISTICS"));

        }
    });

    Button bbuttonteamdetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonteamdetails);
    bbuttonteamdetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.footballmanagerlog.GOTOTEAMDETAILS"));
        }
    });

    Button bbuttonplayerdetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplayerdetails);
    bbuttonplayerdetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.footballmanagerlog.GOTOPLAYERDETAILS"));
        }
    });     


}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can you use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) data storage.

To save a string:

```
SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
editor.putString("stringName", "stringValue");
editor.commit();
```

To get string:

```
mypreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = mypreferences.getString("stringName", "defaultValue");
```

In you code:

```
**teamDetails**
public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  TeamName = getInput.getText().toString();

  SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
  editor.putString("TeamName", TeamName);
  editor.commit();

  Intent TeamNameIntent = new Intent("com.footballmanagerlog.GOTOINGAMEMENU");                          
  startActivity(TeamNameIntent);
}

**inGameMenu**
  setContentView(R.layout.ingamemenu);
  TextView teamname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuteamname); 

  SharedPreferences mypreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  String teamnamestring = mypreferences.getString("TeamName", "no_name");

  teamname.setText(teamnamestring);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I tried doing this but got loads of errors. Im saving a string from one class and trying to load it in the other. Is there any chance that you could put your code in the correct place in mine? I'm not sure what i need to do to be honest. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the string can be edited by an user, and you also want it to appear permanently, perforce there must be a saving mechanism. For a good guide to various ways to save data:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you want this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    getInput.setText(TeamName);
    textOut.setText(TeamName);
}
```